# Reclassifying vector attributes efficiently in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, classification, vector-layer

I have converted a raster file to vector and I am trying to create multiple attributes or levels, for my land classification.

I have multiple values that are 101, 102, 103, 104 etc. where the 100 values = a height class of 0-1 m and the single number codes mean land class. Is there a fast way by using a case statement to classify all 100 values as a height class of 0- 1m and autopopulate it in the attributes table?

I would want to repeat this step of the other 'levels' such as if the wetland is dominated by hardwood, softwood, upland or wetland.

For example: 101, 105, 108, 109, 110, 106 would be classified as having a height class of 0-1m in the height class attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Open the Field Calculator inside the Attribute Table and create a new field of an appropriate type with something like this:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN value > 100 AND value < 200 THEN '0-1'
    WHEN value > 200 AND value < 300 THEN '0-2'
    ...
    ELSE '0-x'
END
```